# count conditional items in list

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, piecewise, logic, counting

I have a list of the form:

`{1,1, (1 if x>y, -1 if y>=x), -1}`

I want to count the number of 1's in the list. The output I'm looking for is something of the form:

`3 if x>y`

`2 if y>= x`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I take it that you execute a function to check if `x>y` and then if the list is already in that form, `Count[list, 1]` should work. Clarity is needed as to how the list looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The problem is that I don't want to evaluate the condition. I want it to give me a list of counts and symbolic conditions.

Comment: But that list as it is cannot be evaluated, right? How do you encode the information that if and else part in the list. I mean I want to just know how have you really stored that list.

Comment: Oh I see. The list is literally of the form in the question, such that some of the entries are piecewise functions. This is why just using Count[list,1] doesn't work---it ignores every entry that is a piecewise expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
countPW[ls_, pat_] :=  Module[{
   cf = MapAt[Count[Flatten@#, pat] &, #, {{1, ;;, 1}, {2}}] &, 
   pwe = PiecewiseExpand[Append[Cases[_If]@ls, Cases[Except[_If]]@ls]]}, 
   PiecewiseExpand[#, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> FullSimplify}] & @ cf @ pwe]
```

***Examples:***

```
list1 = {1, 1, If[x > y, 1, -1], -1};

countPW[list1, -1 | 1]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

```
countPW[list1, 1] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  2 & x\leq y \\
>  3 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
countPW[list1, -1] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  2 & x\leq y \\
>  1 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
list2 = {1, 1, If[x > y, 1, -1], If[z > w, 1, -1], -1};

countPW[list2, -1 | 1]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

```
countPW[list2, 1] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  2 & x\leq y\land w\geq z \\
>  3 & \neg (w<z\veebar x\leq y) \\
>  4 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
countPW[list2, -1] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  3 & x\leq y\land w\geq z \\
>  2 & \neg (w<z\veebar x\leq y) \\
>  1 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
list3 = {1, 1, 2, If[x > y, {1, 2, 3, -1}, -1], If[z > w, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 2, -1}], -1};

countPW[list3, 2 | -1] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  3 & x\leq y\land w<z \\
>  6 & x\leq y\land w\geq z \\
>  4 & x>y\land w<z \\
>  7 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Comment: this is AWESOME, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the conditional expression is written in the Mathematica form

```
expr = {1, 1, If[x > y, 1, -1], -1, If[x > y, 1, -1], -1};
```

then we could define a function

```
Clear[count]
count[expr_, patt_] := Block[{cond, alt1, alt2},
  {cond, alt1, alt2} = 
      FirstCase[expr, item_If :> List @@ item];
      If[cond, 
         Evaluate[Count[expr /. cond :> True, patt]],
             Evaluate[Count[expr /. cond :> False, patt]]]    
]
```

which counts the patterns in the conditional expression

```
count[expr, 1]
(*  If[x > y, 4, 2]  *)

count[expr, -1]
(*  If[x > y, 2, 4]  *)
```

Note that `count` assumes, but does not check for, identical first arguments of each `If`.

Answer (score 0):

In no way is this the best solution, but this does the job.

```
l = Piecewise[{{1, x > y}, {-1, x <= y}}]

list = RandomChoice[{1, -1, l}, 5]
(*{Piecewise[{{1, x > y}, {-1, x <= y}}], -1, 1, Piecewise[{{1, x > y}, {-1, x <= y}}], -1}*)

Count[Assuming[#, Refine /@ list], 1] & /@ {x > y, x <= y}
(*3,1*)
```